# Given $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $\overline{\alpha u} \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, with $\alpha \in C^1 \cap L^{\infty},\nabla \alpha \in L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Given $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\alpha$ a function which verifies $\alpha \in C^1(\Omega)$, $\alpha \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,  $\nabla \alpha \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)^n $ y $supp(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{R}^n-{\partial \Omega}$.

I need to show that:

> $\overline{\alpha u} \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\overline{(\alpha u)}_{x_i}= \overline{\alpha u_{x_i}+\alpha_{x_i}u}$

Where $\bar{f}$ is the extension of a given function $f$, defined as $$\bar{f}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 f(x) & in \ \Omega \\ 
  0 & \quad  \quad \ in \ \mathbb{R}^n-\Omega
\end{matrix}\right.  $$
And $f_{x_i}$ denotes $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$.

I have tried several things, the last one being the one I present here, although it is not completed:

Recall the definition of weak derivative, and pick $\varphi \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\overline{\alpha u} \varphi_{x_i}= \int_{\Omega}\alpha u \varphi_{x_i}=\int_{\Omega}u[(\alpha \varphi)_{x_i}- \alpha_{x_i} \varphi]$

Now it would be great if I could show that $\alpha \varphi$ is actually in $C^1_c(\Omega)$, which would allow us to pass the derivative to $u$ in the first term, but I do not know exactly how to proceed.